# How to return whole objects from group aggregate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a aggregation query like this:

```
db.yc_promotions.aggregate([
{$match:
    {
        city_from: {$in: ['x1','x2','x3']},
        city_to: {$in: ['y1','y2','y3']},
        date_ret: {$lte: "2013-06-30"},
        updated: {"$gte": "2013-02-01"}
    }
},
{$group:
    {
        _id: {city_to: "$city_to"},
        min: { $min: "$total_price" }
    }
}
])
```

the query response is as expected in a form like this:

```
{"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "city_to" : "y1"
        },
        "min" : 2404.72
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "city_to" : "y2"
        },
        "min" : 1619.2
    }
    ...
 ]}
```

But I would like to return the objects with those minimum prices instead of just values and city codes. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to add the other fields with something like the following (I ignored the match):

```
db.test.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: { city_to: "$city_to" },
        min: { $min: "$total_price"  },
        city_from: { $min: "$city_from" }
    } }
);
```

But that doesn't work. As $min would be working on **each** field. Take for example:

```
> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51156a11056d6f966f268f7f"), "city_from" : "LHR", "city_to" : "JFK", "total_price" : 500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51156a1a056d6f966f268f80"), "city_from" : "LHR", "city_to" : "LGA", "total_price" : 400 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51156a1e056d6f966f268f81"), "city_from" : "DUB", "city_to" : "LGA", "total_price" : 400 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51156a27056d6f966f268f82"), "city_from" : "DUB", "city_to" : "JFK", "total_price" : 300 }
> db.test.aggregate( {$group: { _id: { city_to: "$city_to" }, min: { $min: "$total_price"  }, city_from: { $min: "$city_from" } } } );
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "city_to" : "LGA"
            },
            "min" : 400,
            "city_from" : "DUB"
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "city_to" : "JFK"
            },
            "min" : 300,
            "city_from" : "DUB"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The **city_from: LHR** is totally gone, even though both LHR->LGA and DUB->LGA have the same minimum price. **city_from: { $min: "$city_from" }** returns the string minimum of [ DUB, LGA ] only. You can of course have multiple documents that have the same minimum price (400 in this case for both LHR->LGA and DUB->LGA).

You will have to do this in two steps:

```
> result = db.test.aggregate( {$group: { _id: { city_to: "$city_to" }, min: { $min: "$total_price"  } } } );
> final = []
> result.result.forEach(function(entry) { final.push( { city_to: entry._id.city_to, min: entry.min, docs: db.test.aggregate( { $match: { city_to: entry._id.city_to, total_price: entry.min } } ).result } ) } );
```

Which then gives as result:

```
> final
[
    {
        "city_to" : "LGA",
        "min" : 400,
        "docs" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("51156a1a056d6f966f268f80"),
                "city_from" : "LHR",
                "city_to" : "LGA",
                "total_price" : 400
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("51156a1e056d6f966f268f81"),
                "city_from" : "DUB",
                "city_to" : "LGA",
                "total_price" : 400
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "city_to" : "JFK",
        "min" : 300,
        "docs" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("51156a27056d6f966f268f82"),
                "city_from" : "DUB",
                "city_to" : "JFK",
                "total_price" : 300
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Noting his last comment: "Find the lowest price for each of the connections (city_from, city_to) and get the object with that minimum price" How will getting a list of _ids get the lowest object? It sounds like it makes his life harder

Comment: But the other point: "get the object with that minimum price" which means it is only one document that has the min price he is looking for.

Comment: Hmm too bad that's the only way :(

Answer (score 1):

When you group you have to tell MongoDB what value you want for the other fields. So where you have:

```
min: { $min: "$total_price" }
```

You need to replicate this field and rename it for each and every field of the projected object you wish to return, in this case:

```
city_to: { $min: "$city_to" },
city_from: { $min: "$city_from" }
// etc
```

So a full example would be:

```
db.yc_promotions.aggregate([
{$match:
    {
        city_from: {$in: ['x1','x2','x3']},
        city_to: {$in: ['y1','y2','y3']},
        date_ret: {$lte: "2013-06-30"},
        updated: {"$gte": "2013-02-01"}
    }
},
{$group:
    {
        _id: {city_to: "$city_to"},
        min: { $min: "$total_price" },
        city_to: { $min: "$city_to" },
        city_from: { $min: "$city_from" }        
    }
}
])
```

See how I added `city_to` and `city_from` to the `$group`? Just do that for each of the fields you wish to project within the `$group`.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is the first time I'm using MongoDb and I don't really understand how to do it base on your answer. Can you please give an example? Thanks!

Comment: @Ralphz Added a little exmaple, let me kow if you need more help

Comment: Wouldn't that for example get the _minimum_ city_from in the group no matter if the cheapest price was for another city_from? Sincere question, I come from SQL where that looks strange :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Indeed you would change that to whatever you need, SQL, depending on the db, will get either min or max of each of your grouped fields. Since it depends upon the database here (MySQL/MSSQL) it is normally better to specify the min and max yourself in SQL as well so it is consistent across techs

Comment: @Ralphz Wait re-reading your question here, do you want rows within that group to be returned as well? it is unclear

Comment: @Sammaye The title says "return whole objects from group aggregate", so I assumed that was the intention.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I dunno, I am unclear, plus I dunno what the object is since it is not provided in the question, only the aggregation function is

Comment: What I'm trying to find is "Find the lowest price for each of the connections (city_from, city_to) and get the object with that minimum price" The example that Sammaye gave me exactly what Joachim Isaksson said.

Comment: @Ralphz So basically your looking for the min valueof the grouped document? Since if you get the $min price you also want the $min everything else, right? So the example above should work

Comment: You can't use $min like this, see my answer.

Comment: @Derick Yea I thought about it sometime later but I wasn't quite sure how to solve this problem properly.